# Can a US city charge money for people wanting to live there?

Tags: united-states, taxes, citizenship

For example,

A mayor may say, only residents can vote. And each resident must pay $20k to buy residency at market price.

Can a mayor do that?

In general, is it possible that a city is "privatized" like malls? In private malls, the malls decide who can be a tenant on those malls right. Can a city be like that?

For example, can an experimental city levy "poll taxes" or give resident dividend?

Say a city is filled with ancaps. Say those ancaps want only ancaps to be able to vote for cities' policy. They may want to say, you know, this city is privately owned and only shareholders can stay. Hence, only those who think ancap is so good they're willing to pay $20k for it stay in the city.

Comment: 1) What is a "major"? 2) To live in a city, you need to pay taxes and buy/rent a place to live (2 transactions that might also be taxed). Can you clarify how this "charge" differ from that?

Comment: Property tax, vehicle registration, toll roads, and other local taxes are all examples of this.

Comment: Can a city keep the poor out of the city? Something like private owners can kick anyone out of their private properties? Can cities be "membership only"?

Comment: The notion of ancaps using a municipal government to charge people for the right to live in a given area is rather contradictory, I think. It's called *anarcho*-capitalism for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know the Reedy Creek Improvement District (AKA the part of Disney World that is managing utility services, building codes and inspections, and emergency services) keeps tight control on the "city" government by basically making it a company town.  Only Disney Employees and their families live there and can thus vote.  I'm not sure what the rule for purchasing these houses are (I had an employee friend sneak me behind the parks to see one neighborhood... it's very well hidden) so I don't know if they charge people for the houses.   RCID can do this because they lobbied the State of Florida to give them wide berth in the law to such an extent that they only pay property taxes and submit to elevator inspections when interacting with the state... everything else is governed by local laws (At the time the group of companies asking for this exemption lobbied Florida, FL wasn't aware they were all owned by Disney... and now a days they tend to not threaten Disney with regulations because they're bringing in the tourist dollars, which is where Florida gets a good deal of its taxes from.

Comment: Isn't all the land in RCID owned by Disney? The wikipedia page suggests that all land there is owned by Disney or Disney executives chosen specifically to act as the Board of Supervisors that governs the district.

Comment: Yes.   It's a company town.  RCID is a Disney subsidiary that runs most of the services for the parks that would be taken care of by a city ordinarily.  As part of the charter, the citizens vote on the governing board, and since all of the citizens are Disney employees who are typically higher in the ranks than your typical cast member, they tend to vote the Party line... sorry, company line.

Answer (score 3):

> A major may say, only residents can vote.

Isn't that the case already?

> And each resident must pay $20k to buy residency at market price.
>
> Can a major do that?

Not arbitrarily like that. They'd expose themselves to anti-discrimination laws in some form or another.

> Can a US city charge money for people wanting to live there?

That's de facto the case already, owing to property taxes.